# How can I resolve a 'Permission Denied' error while using Document AI API with OAuth2.0?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, identity-management, cloud-document-ai

I am having an issue with Document AI Authorization. When I create an access token and send it with the document ai API it shows me Permission Denied Error. The Oauth2.0 is only working for those users who are added as an owner to IAM Permissions

Can anyone tell me which service account is connected with my API Call because I am not adding anything related to service account in my API Call.

Or if anyone can please guide me through the issue

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' denied on resource '//documentai.googleapis.com/projects/205806916918/locations/us/processors/1c3f33f7cb3a533e' (or it may not exist).",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
                "domain": "documentai.googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "resource": "projects/205806916918/locations/us/processors/1c3f33f7cb3a533e",
                    "permission": "documentai.processors.processOnline"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[image]

These are my IAM Permissions

I have tried giving owner roles to every service account but it still does not work out.

Comment: Can you share how do you performt he call to the endpoint?

Comment: https://api.postman.com/collections/20524671-85ef1dbf-f44e-42bd-9e14-f3595c7a3102?access_key=PMAT-01H0SS82EPJCXW546FTT0CREE0

This is my Postman's Collection JSON. Check this

Answer (score 1):

You should only need `roles/documentai.apiUser` for whichever account is being used as the sender of the API request.

Which service account is used depends on how you're sending the request. Are you making it from a Compute Engine VM, App Engine, local machine, cloud shell? Are you using a REST API call, Client Libraries, etc?

Likely you're not using one of the service accounts with permissions or haven't set up application default credentials. I recommend following the [authentication guide for Google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication)

Comment: I am using REST API Call using Postman. Can you guide me how can i check which service account is used for REST API Call?

Comment: https://api.postman.com/collections/20524671-85ef1dbf-f44e-42bd-9e14-f3595c7a3102?access_key=PMAT-01H0SS82EPJCXW546FTT0CREE0

This is My Postman Collection's Link that contains all the API Calls that i am working on

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. For Postman, you'll need to do some extra configuration to make the authentication work with Google Cloud APIs. Here's the official docs from Postman https://www.postman.com/speeding-resonance-133102/workspace/google-cloud-api/documentation/12689164-9400e5f3-afac-4759-afe4-630a3842b2eb

And another guide that shows the process https://www.vulongtran.com/how-to-use-postman-with-google-cloud-platform-apis

Comment: Actually the thing is that everything works fine with the users(emails) that have owner access to the Google Cloud Project but if i login with any new user and get access token it is not working

I am using Oauth2.0 Token to authorize my Document AI API but when i use Oauth2.0 for a new user or any use other then the one that is in the google cloud project as an owner it is giving me the permissions denied error while accessing the Document AI API

Comment: Everything works fine when i use the user's email who is the owner of the project but when i try to create access token with a new user it is no working

Comment: Did you give the other accounts the IAM role `roles/documentai.apiUser` or specific permission `documentai.processors.processOnline`

Comment: Yes I have given all of the accounts permission as Document AI Owner but still not working